# Derivation of Klein Gordon propagator by Generating Functional

Tags: homework-and-exercises, path-integral, greens-functions, klein-gordon-equation, propagator

I am studying Generating functionals in the path integral formulation of QFT. The formalism is done via Gaussian integrals which require the inverse of a function defined as:

$\int A(x,z)  A^{-1}(z,y) d^4z = \delta^4(x-y)$

Using this, to derive the Klein-Gordon Feynman propagator, one arrives at:

$A(x,y) = i(\partial^\mu\partial_\mu + m^2 - i\epsilon)$

Now using the above formula, I need to derive the inverse which will give me the form of the generating functional. But I am stuck with the calculation. I know that the inverse comes out to be proportional to the Feynman propagator:

$\Delta_F(x-y) = \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ie^{-ik(x-y)}}{k^2 - m^2 + i\epsilon}$

and the fact that it is a Green's function to the KG equation:

$(\partial^\mu\partial_\mu + m^2 -i\epsilon)\Delta_F(x-y) = -i\delta^4(x-y)$

but I am not being to derive the inverse to be as expected. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried applying the Fourier transform to the last equation in your question? You will get an algebraic equation for the Fourier image of $\Delta_F$, which after the inverse Fourier transform will give the expected result.